# ExecutorService doesn't execute Runnables in JUnit tests

Tags: java, android, multithreading, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I have an executor service that I want to test.

I have few tasks (Runnables) which need to be called, then call **wait()** and a dummy timer calls **notify()** after few seconds.

I've made this to check if all tasks are executed in sequence and after some periods of time.

The problem is that **run()** method of my Runnable is not called at all. I've setup a breakpoint and the code execution doesn't reach it.

In plain coding it works well. Tasks are queued, they call **wait()** until some response is not gained or timeout is triggered, they call **notify()** and next task is executed.

The problem is when I run tests.

Are there any thoughts about this?

Comment: While debugging, did you used Suspend VM / Suspend Thread..? Can you also share your code for reference.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen when the `test` method exits before other threads hit `wait` and `notify`.

Try call:

```
executorService.shutdown();
try {
    executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {

}
```

before exits the `test` method. It will block the test method until all `Runnable` finish.